# Specify Responsive Input Keyboard Type

Tags: javascript, validation, responsive-design, uikeyboardtype

I'm building a website that I would like to have a good responsive interface - a big part of what that means for this site is semantic input types so the right mobile keyboard pops up (ie. numberpad for tel).

What I'd like is to pop up the telephone-numberpad keyboard for the *password field* (the app will encourage something more like a pin) - is it possible to bring up the right (telephone or number) keyboard while keeping the `***`'s that hides your password as you type?

Can I popup the number-keyboard but still let the user type in letters and any input they want? I know there is often some browser input validation for inputs (like if it's `type="email"` chrome prompts "you need to include an '@' sybol!") which I'd like to override.

Comment: Why would you feature digits if letters are also allowed? It will make the passwords considerably weaker.

Comment: the goal is a UX choice - we want to encourage pin-like passwords for quick use with generally non-critical data, but allow people to choose more secure passwords if they want it, even if they'll lose some efficiency/speed-of-use.